# How do I calculate a running total when using a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around this code (I am very new so please be gentle), in an attempt to write a program to track calories, I can't get the code:

```
caloriesPerMeal = int(input('Enter calories eaten per meal: '))
```

to add onto itself when it looks back and asks again if I want to enter another meal(as shown below):

```
keepGoing = input('Do you want to enter another meal? (Enter yes or no) ')
```

The entire code I have is:

```
keepGoing = 'yes'
totalCalories = 0
#Calories per Day
maxCaloriesPerDay = int(input('How many calories per day would you like to consume? '))
while keepGoing == 'yes':
    #Get number of calories per meal
    caloriesPerMeal = int(input('Enter calories eaten per meal: '))
    totalCalories += totalCalories + caloriesPerMeal
#See if user wants to input another meal
    keepGoing = input('Do you want to enter another meal? (Enter yes or no) ')
#Calculate calories under/over per day
if totalCalories >= maxCaloriesPerDay:
    print('You are', maxCaloriesPerDay - totalCalories, 'calories over your maximum calories per 
 day.')
elif totalCalories <= maxCaloriesPerDay:
     print('You are', maxCaloriesPerDay - totalCalories, 'calories under your maximum calories per 
day. ')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do :

`totalCalories = totalCalories + caloriesPerMeal`

Or :

`totalCalories += caloriesPerMeal`

Because saying that `totalCalories += totalCalories + caloriesPerMeal` means that
`totalCalories = 2*totalCalories + caloriesPerMeal`

Comment: wow I feel like a dummy for this haha such a simple solution, but thank you so so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
keepGoing = 'yes'
totalCalories = 0
#Calories per Day
maxCaloriesPerDay = int(input('How many calories per day would you like to consume? '))
while keepGoing == 'yes':
    #Get number of calories per meal
    caloriesPerMeal = int(input('Enter calories eaten per meal: '))
    totalCalories += caloriesPerMeal
#See if user wants to input another meal
    keepGoing = input('Do you want to enter another meal? (Enter yes or no) ')
#Calculate calories under/over per day
if totalCalories >= maxCaloriesPerDay:
    print('You are', maxCaloriesPerDay - totalCalories, 'calories over your maximum calories per day.')
elif totalCalories <= maxCaloriesPerDay:
     print('You are', maxCaloriesPerDay - totalCalories, 'calories under your maximum calories per day. ')
```

Comment: thank you for the help, such an easy solution I just looked past :)